# How do I access nested hashmap java

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I've a

```
Map<String, Object> response = {
    sendResponse = {
        return = {
            SendResponse = {
                txnID = 4fa160ce-638f-4556-9313-afbef543fadd,
                emailTypeID = 1020261131,
                txnStatusCode = 1,
                txnStatusMessage = OK,
                status = [
                    {   CommunicationStatus = {
                            type = EMAIL,
                            statusCode = 1,
                            statusMessage = OK
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to extract "statusMessage" from response Map. Please advise.

The runtime types of nested objects are `LinkedHashMap<K,V>` and Type of the Status is `ArrayList` which has `LinkedHashMap<K,V>` inside.

I tried using get() method for example like below but I'm facing casting warnings.
Ex: response.get("sendResponse")).get("return")).get("SendResponse").get("status").get(0).get("CommunicationStatus").get(statusMessage);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. After the downvotes you may want to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (once more) and see if you can improve your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi, The runtime types of nested objects are LinkedHashMap<K,V> and Type of the Status is ArrayList which has LinkedHashMap<K,V> inside and we are using Jackson library

Comment: Thanks for providing more information, it’s helpful. It’s also best to do it as edits to the question. You have got an edit link under the question. Only this time I edited for you. Next time will be your turn. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a bit alright.

```
    Map<String, Object> response = new LinkedHashMap<>(Map.of(
            "sendResponse", new LinkedHashMap<>(Map.of(
                    "return", new LinkedHashMap<>(Map.of(
                            "SendResponse", new LinkedHashMap<>(Map.of(
                                    "txnId", "4fa160ce-638f-4556-9313-afbef543fadd",
                                    "status", new ArrayList<Object>(List.of(
                                            new LinkedHashMap<>(Map.of(
                                                    "CommunicationStatus", new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(Map.of(
                                                            "type", "EMAIL",
                                                            "statusMessage", "OK"))))))))))))));
    
    System.out.println(response);
    
    Map<?, ?> sendResponse = (Map<?, ?>) response.get("sendResponse");
    Map<?, ?> returnMap = (Map<?, ?>) sendResponse.get("return");
    Map<?, ?> sendResponseCapitalS = (Map<?, ?>) returnMap.get("SendResponse");
    List<?> status = (List<?>) sendResponseCapitalS.get("status");
    Optional<Map<?, ?>> statusEmail = (Optional<Map<?, ?>>) status.stream()
            .map(m -> ((Map<?, ?>) m).get("CommunicationStatus"))
            .filter(m -> ((Map<?, ?>) m).get("type").equals("EMAIL"))
            .findAny();
    Optional<Object> statusMessage = statusEmail.map(m -> m.get("statusMessage"));
    
    statusMessage.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

I have left out some uninteresting bits from your map, it should make no difference. I am printing the map I have constructed for you to check that it looks like yours (only with a few bits left out). Output from the above snippet is:

> ```
> {sendResponse={return={SendResponse={txnId=4fa160ce-638f-4556-9313-afbef543fadd,status=[{CommunicationStatus={statusMessage=OK, type=EMAIL}}]}}}}
> OK
> ```

I am using a stream operation to take out the map from the list where type is `EMAIL`. Please check whether this is correct for your requirements.

Edit: You and I have both observed the warning *Type safety: Unchecked cast from Optional<capture#16-of ?> to Optional<Map>*. I found no good way of getting rid of it. The following variant of the last two lines before the final printout do not show the warning:

```
    Optional<?> statusEmail = status.stream()
            .map(m -> ((Map<?, ?>) m).get("CommunicationStatus"))
            .filter(m -> ((Map<?, ?>) m).get("type").equals("EMAIL"))
            .findAny();
    Optional<Object> statusMessage = statusEmail.map(m -> ((Map<?, ?>) m).get("statusMessage"));
```

However, they give less information about the type of `statusEmail`, which I find a clear disadvantage, which is why I opted for posting the first variant above in spite of the warning.

Comment: I'm seeing a typesafety warning (Type safety: Unchecked cast from Optional<capture#16-of ?> to Optional<Map<?,?>>) at this place - Optional<Map<?, ?>> statusEmail = (Optional<Map<?, ?>>) status.stream()
            .map(m -> ((Map<?, ?>) m).get("CommunicationStatus"))
            .filter(m -> ((Map<?, ?>) m).get("type").equals("EMAIL"))
            .findAny();

Comment: Thank you for your time. Is it appropriate to use casting Map<?, ?> like this?

Comment: For the type safety warning see my edit. For the cast to `Map<?, ?>`, it’s a matter of taste. I can’t see we can do without a cast. You may cast to for example `LinkedHashMap<String, ?>` if you prefer. It doesn’t make much of a difference IMHO.